# Windows 10 can’t boot after latest fall creators update 1709. USB safe mode not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, safe-mode

I updated my hp envy running windows 10 professional this morning to the fall creators update 1709. After successful update and restart I tried logging into my profile but the screen just goes black and returns to the locked screen.

I then tried booting into safe mode to uninstall the update using the shift+restart combination many times to no avail. I then created a usb recovery disk with a friends computer and am trying to log in to safe mode from there. With no boot options I am forced to try to use the command line to activate safe mode but the

bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal 
doesn't work with the error:

The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found.

I have also used diskpart to check if my partitions are available but even though it shows that my recovery partition still exists safe mode and the recovery options are not working when i use the normal shift+restart combination.

I also ran commands like bootrec /fixmbr, bootrec /rebuildBCD, and bootsect /nt60 E:. These worked fine, but every time I try to run bootrec /fixboot, I get an error saying the volume does not contain a recognized file system. Currently i am running chkdsk E: /r to see if there are any errors with my drive even though i strongly doubt it.

I'm just trying to remove the latest windows update through safemode, but I can't get to safe mode for some reason. I also tried rolling the update back and going to a restore point through the recovery USB, but those methods didn't work either.

Comment: If you already attempted to remove the update then booting to safe mode won’t result in a different outcome

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I never tried to previously remove the update. The attempt to go to safe mode is so I can get rid of the update. I just can’t get there. Also I think one of the commands I ran messed up my boot because now when I try to reboot the system says an operating system is not found. I know my files are still there though and nothing has been deleted from my hard drive